# Error calling function Can not convert type

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, comparable

Writing a program for class and am trying to call a function "build" I keep getting a error saying can not cannot convert parameter 1 from 'TreeNode *' to 'std::string'
The class for Tree and TreeNode are written in other header files but are included
The Function build is supposed to create a tree from the inorder and preorder sorted.
The main section was given to us that way we were supposed to write the function.
Don't need help trying to figure out the function but would like help in fixing this error.

```
template <class Comparable>
TreeNode<Comparable> *build(Comparable prefix[], Comparable infix[] , int Pi , int Pj , int   Ii , int Ij);

int main()
{

    string in[] = {"Apr", "Aug" ,"Dec", "Feb", "Jul", "Jun",  "Mar", "May", "Nov", "Oct",      "Sep"} ;
    string pre[] = {"Jul", "Feb", "Apr", "Aug", "Dec", "Mar", "Jun", "May", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov"} ;
    Tree<string> *tree = new Tree<string>(build(pre,in,0,10,0,10)) ;
}


TreeNode<Comparable> *build(Comparable prefix[], Comparable infix[] , int Pi , int Pj , int Ii , int Ij)
{
    int preIndex = 0;
    TreeNode<Comparable> rNode = new TreeNode<Comparable>(prefix[preIndex]);
    if(Ii > Ij)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    if(preIndex>=Pj)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    int i =0;
    for (i=Ii; i<Ij;i++)
    {
        if(infix[i]==rNode.item)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    rNode.left=build(Comparable prefix[], Comparable infix[] , int Pi , int Pj , int Ii , int Ij-1);
    rNode.right=build(Comparable prefix[], Comparable infix[] , int Pi , int Pj , int Ii+1, int Ij);*/
}
```

TreeNode Class

```
#ifndef _TREENODE_H
#define _TREENODE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class Comparable>

class TreeNode {

public:     
    Comparable  item;         // The data in this node.
    TreeNode *left;   // Pointer to the left subtree.
    TreeNode *right;  // Pointer to the right subtree.

    TreeNode  (Comparable value) 
    {
        item=value;
        left=NULL;
        right=NULL;
    };     // Constructor.  Make a node containing value.
    TreeNode  (Comparable value, TreeNode *leftTree, TreeNode *rightTree) 
    {
        item=value;
        left=leftTree;
        right=rightTree;
    };// Constructor. 
    template <class Comparable>
    friend class Tree ;
 };
 #endif
```

Tree Class (Not finished clearly)

```
#ifndef _TREE_H
#define _TREE_H

#include <iostream>
#include "TreeNode.h"
using namespace std;

template <class Comparable>
class Tree{
public :
    TreeNode< Comparable> *root ;

    Tree () 
    {    // dedault constructor 
        root = NULL ;
    }

    Tree  (Comparable value)  // constructor ;create a single node tree
    {
        root = new TreeNode<Comparable>(value);
    };  // constructor        

    Tree(Comparable value , Tree left, Tree right) 
    {
        root = new TreeNode<Comparable>(value, left, right);
    };
    Tree build(Comparable prefix[], Comparable infix[] , int Pi , int Pj , int Ii , int Ij)
    {
    }
    Tree (Tree  &other)    // copy constructor
    {
        copyTree(other.root, root);
    };

    /*Tree(TreeNode *r )   //  constructor taking a pointer to a tree node
    {
        root=new TreeNode<Comparable>(r->item,r->left,r->right);
    };*/
    Tree & operator = (const Tree &rhs)         // overload assignment operator
    {
        copyTree(rhs.root,root);
    };

    ~Tree()  // destructor
    {
        delete left;
        delete right;
    }



    void preorder()
    {
        if(root != NULL)
        {
            leftTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            rightTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            cout<<root->item<<” “;
            leftTemp=leftTemp->left;
            preorder();
            rightTemp = rightTemp->right;
            preorder();
        }

    }
    void postorder()
    {
        if(root != NULL)
        {
            leftTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            rightTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            leftTemp=leftTemp->left;
            postorder(root->left);
            rightTemp = rightTemp->right;
            postorder(root->right);
            cout<<root->item<<” “;
        } 

    }
    void inorder()
    {
        if(root != NULL)
        {
            leftTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            rightTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            leftTemp=leftTemp->left;
            inorder();
            cout<<root->item<<” “;
            rightTemp = rightTemp->right;
            inorder();
        }
    }

       // the following recursive functions that print the tree node and its level #

    void preorder(int level) 
    {
        if(root != NULL)
        {
            leftTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            rightTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            cout<<root->item<<” “<<level<<” “;
            leftTemp=leftTemp->left;
            preorder(level+1);
            rightTemp = rightTemp->right;
            preorder(level+1);
        }
    }
    void postorder(int level)
    {
        if(root != NULL)
        {
            leftTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            rightTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            leftTemp=leftTemp->left;
            postorder(level+1);
            rightTemp = rightTemp->right;
            postorder(level+1);
            cout<<root->item<<” “<<level<<” “;
        } 
    }
    void inorder(int level )
    {
        if(root != NULL)
        {
            leftTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            rightTemp = new TreeNode<Comparable>(root->item,root->left,root->right);
            leftTemp=leftTemp->left;
            inorder(level+1);
            cout<<root->item<<” “<<level<<” “;
            rightTemp = rightTemp->right;
            inorder(level+1);
        }
    }

    // the following recursive function prints the  tree node with its parent and level number 

    /*void preorder(TreeNode< Comparable> *p , int level) ;  // recursive preorder with level #

    void postorder(TreeNode< Comparable> *p , int level) ;  // recursive postorder with level #

    void inorder(TreeNode< Comparable> *p , int level) ;  // recursive inorder with level #

    void byLevel();  // print the tree by level , use of STL queue class

    /*int weight() ;   // returns the total number of nodes in the tree

    int height();    //  returns the height of the tree


    // the following three are non-recursive version use of STL stack class

    /*void pre() ;        // non-recursive preorder   
    void in() ;         // non-recursive inorder() 
    void post() ;       // non-recursive postorder() 


    // static function build2Tree build a nearly perfect balanced binary tree: detail will discuss in class
    static Tree *build2Tree( Comparable arr [] , int n);  */
    void copyTree(TreeNode<Comparable>* &copiedTreeRoot, TreeNode<Comparable>* otherTreeRoot)
    {
        if(otherTreeRoot == NULL)
        {
            copiedTreeRoot = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            copiedTreeRoot = new nodeType<Comparable>;
            copiedTreeRoot->info = otherTreeRoot->info;
            copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->llink, otherTreeRoot->llink);
            copyTree(copiedTreeRoot->rlink, otherTreeRoot->rlink);
        }
    }//end copyTree

} ;
#endif
```

edit: added tree/treenode classes

Comment: insufficient data. Where are you returning anything other than NULL?

Comment: @john Comparable = a template. It can be anything

Comment: its a function that makes a binary tree so it returns NULL when it reaches the end of the branch and won't keep calling itself to build the tree

Comment: @PrototypeStark Yes got that, I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @SomeAsianGuy can you post more code? or the line where the error is?

Comment: It errors on line Tree<string> *tree = new Tree<string>(build(pre,in,0,10,0,10)) ; Theres not much more except the TreeNode class and Tree class in the header file Should i add those?  This was the test CPP file we got from our teacher to test our program  The rest is just calling functions from Tree class to print out what is in the tree

Comment: @SomeAsianGuy is Tree constructor expecting a TreeNode pointer?

Comment: @SomeAsianGuy add it for the sake of good.

Comment: @PrototypeStark It can take a TreeNode pointer or it can take just the value or the value and both left and right tree pointers

Comment: lets see the code @SomeAsianGuy

Comment: @PrototypeStark Wanna try and work out the rest of the functions in Tree class bymyself btw so i can actully learn something this error is just screwing up the test main mostly on me

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
TreeNode<Comparable> rNode = new TreeNode<Comparable>(prefix[preIndex]);
```

This should be

```
TreeNode<Comparable> * rNode = ...
                     ^
                     note star
```

Now lets explain error:

In this line you are trying to *construct* `TreeNode<Comparable>` from the expression of type `TreeNode<Comparable>*`, but it seems `TreeNode<Comparable>` has constructor, not marked as `explicit`, accepting `std::string`. Like

```
template <typename T>
struct TreeNode
{
TreeNode(const std::string&) {}
};
```

The only possible way for compiler to interpret your code is to cast `TreeNode<Comparable>` to `std::string` to call that constructor. But it can't. So you get such an error.

Now, you of cause have to asses `rNode` with `->` insread of `.`, as it became a *pointer*.

---

Also, this code

```
rNode.left=build(Comparable prefix[], Comparable infix[] , int Pi , int Pj , int Ii , int Ij-1);
    rNode.right=build(Comparable prefix[], Comparable infix[] , int Pi , int Pj , int Ii+1, int Ij);*/
```

looks invalid. It should be

```
rNode->left=build(prefix, infix, Pi, Pj, Ii, Ij-1);
rNode->right=build(prefix, infix, Pi, Pj, Ii+1, Ij);
```

(I assume it is typo)

---

The same thing as in first point happens when you try to create `Tree` here:

```
Tree<string> *tree = new Tree<string>(build(pre,in,0,10,0,10)) ;
```

`build` returns you `TreeNoed<std::string>`, but your `Tree<std::string>` has a constructor accepting `std::string` (that is `Comparable`)

you probably need to add new constructor to `Tree`:

```
Tree(TreeNode< Comparable>* r):root(r){}
```

Comment: still getting the same error even with the pointer star added

Comment: @SomeAsianGuy, _exactly the same_?

Comment: I think ur last edit is right i accidently commented out the constructor that takes a pointer  let me fix that and see if it works now Yea it works now Thanks alot.  Hate when i make these stupid mistakes

Answer (score 0):

```
Tree  (Comparable value)  // constructor ;create a single node tree
    {
        root = new TreeNode<Comparable>(value);
    }
```

here is your error. It was expecting a "string" and you passed a pointer to it.

And here

```
TreeNode  (Comparable value) 
    {
        item=value;
        left=NULL;
        right=NULL;
    }
```

Same thing, expecting a Comparable(that is a string) and getting a TreeNode *

Also what's with some of those semicolons after functions?
And yes, that commented block that accepts a TreeNode *. Uncomment that to know :-)

Comment: Working off a templete we get from our teacher and it came like that lol.

Comment: @SomeAsianGuy :-) I know teachers can be tricky. :-P but its important exercise to learn you know